# Botão não funciona quando o código é agregado ao AbstractTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

Criei um projeto teste para implementar em um projeto maior de uma tabela com um botão como um dos elementos da linha. Ela funciona perfeitamente, mas quando vou tentar agregar ao meu código o botão não executa a ação que foi programada. Ele está sendo feito com AbstractTableModel. Alguém tem uma ideia de onde pode estar o problema?

Projeto testável do que preciso fazer:

Tabela.java

```
public class Tabela extends JFrame{

    public Tabela(){
        super("Teste de Componentes na Coluna");

        Object[][] data = {
            {"1", "Azul", new Integer(2013), "21"},
            {"2", "Roxo", new Integer(2013), "1"},
            {"3", "Preto", new Integer(2013), "2"},
            {"4", "Vermelho", new Integer(2013), "8"},
            {"5", "Rosa", new Integer(2013), "70"},
            {"6", "Verde", new Integer(2013), "10"}
        };

        String columnHeaders[] = {"Position", "Color", "Last Year Won", "Trophies"};


        JTable table = new JTable(data,columnHeaders);

        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new ButtonRenderer());
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(new ButtonEditor(new JTextField()));

        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
        getContentPane().add(pane);
        setSize(450,100);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tabela t = new Tabela();
        t.setVisible(true);
    }

    class ButtonRenderer extends JButton implements TableCellRenderer{

        public ButtonRenderer(){
            setOpaque(true);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object obj, 
                boolean selected, boolean focused, int row, int col) {
            setText((obj == null) ? "":obj.toString());
            return this;
        }

    }

    class ButtonEditor extends DefaultCellEditor{
    protected JButton btn;
    private String lbl;
    private Boolean clicked;

    public ButtonEditor(JTextField txt){
        super(txt);
        btn = new JButton();
        btn.setOpaque(true);

        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        fireEditingStopped();
                    }
        });
    }

    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object obj, boolean selected, int row, int col){
        lbl = (obj == null) ? "":obj.toString();
        btn.setText(lbl);
        clicked = true;
        return btn;
    }

        public Object getCellEditorValue(){
    if(clicked){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(btn, lbl + "Clicked");
    }
    clicked = false;
    return new String(lbl);
}

        public boolean stopCellEditing(){
                clicked = false;
                return super.stopCellEditing();
        }

        protected void fireEditingStopped(){
                super.fireEditingStopped();
        }
}

}
```

---

Projeto onde a tabela deve ser agregada:

PendenciaView.java

```
public class PendenciaView extends JPanel {
    private JTextField txtId;

    PendenciaTableModel tableModel = new PendenciaTableModel();
    private final JTable table;

    /**
     * Create the panel.
     */
    public PendenciaView() {
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(794, 548);

        JLabel lblListaDePendencias = new JLabel("Lista de Pend\u00EAncias:");
        lblListaDePendencias.setBounds(10, 11, 120, 14);
        add(lblListaDePendencias);

        JLabel lblFiltrarPor = new JLabel("Filtrar por:");
        lblFiltrarPor.setBounds(10, 464, 60, 14);
        add(lblFiltrarPor);

        JLabel lblCategoria = new JLabel("Categoria:");
        lblCategoria.setBounds(89, 489, 60, 14);
        add(lblCategoria);

        JComboBox cmbCategoria = new JComboBox();
        cmbCategoria.setBounds(160, 486, 150, 20);
        cmbCategoria.addItem("Todas");
        cmbCategoria.addItem("Pedido");
        cmbCategoria.addItem("Produto");
        cmbCategoria.addItem("Categoria");
        cmbCategoria.addItem("Comprador");      
        add(cmbCategoria);

        JLabel lblDataDeInicio = new JLabel("Data de In\u00EDcio:");
        lblDataDeInicio.setBounds(327, 486, 90, 14);
        add(lblDataDeInicio);

        JDateChooser dcDataDeInicio = new JDateChooser();
        dcDataDeInicio.setBounds(427, 486, 130, 20);        
        add(dcDataDeInicio);
        dcDataDeInicio.setDateFormatString("dd/MM/yyyy");

        JLabel lblDataDeFim = new JLabel("Data de Fim:");
        lblDataDeFim.setBounds(567, 489, 77, 14);
        add(lblDataDeFim);

        JDateChooser dcDataDeFim = new JDateChooser();      
        dcDataDeFim.setBounds(654, 486, 130, 20);
        add(dcDataDeFim);
        dcDataDeFim.setDateFormatString("dd/MM/yyyy");

        JLabel lblId = new JLabel("ID:");
        lblId.setBounds(10, 489, 15, 14);
        add(lblId);

        txtId = new JTextField();
        txtId.setBounds(28, 486, 51, 20);
        add(txtId);
        txtId.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnFiltrar = new JButton("Filtrar");
        btnFiltrar.setBounds(695, 514, 89, 23);
        add(btnFiltrar);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(10, 31, 774, 380);
        add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        table = new JTable(tableModel);
        table.setBounds(0, 0, 774, 380);
        panel.add(table);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollPane.setBounds(0, 0, 774, 380);
        panel.add(scrollPane);

        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);

        JButton btnRemoverPendencias = new JButton("Remover Pend\u00EAncias");
        btnRemoverPendencias.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                //Remove uma linha
                if(table.getSelectedRow() != -1){
                      tableModel.removeRow(table.getSelectedRow());
                }
            }
        });
        btnRemoverPendencias.setBounds(10, 422, 157, 23);
        add(btnRemoverPendencias);

        //"Selecionar", "ID", "Pendência", "Data e Hora", "Descrição", "Detalhes"
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(70);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMaxWidth(50);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setMaxWidth(180);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setMaxWidth(100);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setMaxWidth(300);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setMaxWidth(80);

        PendenciaModel pm = new PendenciaModel();
        pm.setSelecionado(true);
        pm.setId(1);
        pm.setPendencia("BlaBlaBla");
        Date d = new Date();
        pm.setDataHora(d);
        pm.setDescricao("Erafoene vpanpvev np aevnrvpnaep");
        pm.setDetalhes("Abrir");

        tableModel.addRow(pm);

        PendenciaModel pm2 = new PendenciaModel();
        pm2.setSelecionado(true);
        pm2.setId(2);
        pm2.setPendencia("Vdioandd");
        Date d2 = new Date();
        pm2.setDataHora(d2);
        pm2.setDescricao("abdcdgae aefin aefioanfe aiefn");
        pm2.setDetalhes("Abrir");

        tableModel.addRow(pm2);

        Object[][] data = {
                {true, 1, "Azul", new Date(), "Bçlasncaio evwiwwe wavejh", "Abrir"},
                {true, 1, "Roxo", new Date(), "Bçlasncaio evwiwwe wavejh", "Abrir"},
                {true, 1, "Verde", new Date(), "Bçlasncaio evwiwwe wavejh", "Abrir"},
                {true, 1, "Rosa", new Date(), "Bçlasncaio evwiwwe wavejh", "Abrir"},
                {true, 1, "Branco", new Date(), "Bçlasncaio evwiwwe wavejh", "Abrir"},
            };


        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setCellRenderer(new ButtonRenderer());
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setCellEditor(new ButtonEditor(new JTextField()));


    }

       class ButtonRenderer extends JButton implements TableCellRenderer{

            public ButtonRenderer(){
                setOpaque(true);
            }

            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object obj, 
                    boolean selected, boolean focused, int row, int col) {
                setText((obj == null) ? "":obj.toString());
                return this;
            }

        }

        class ButtonEditor extends DefaultCellEditor{
        protected JButton btn;
        private String lbl;
        private Boolean clicked;

        public ButtonEditor(JTextField txt){
            super(txt);
            btn = new JButton();
            btn.setOpaque(true);

            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            fireEditingStopped();
                        }
            });
        }

        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object obj, boolean selected, int row, int col){
            lbl = (obj == null) ? "":obj.toString();
            btn.setText(lbl);
            clicked = true;
            return btn;
        }

            public Object getCellEditorValue(){
        if(clicked){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(btn, lbl + "Clicked");
        }
        clicked = false;
        return new String(lbl);
    }

            public boolean stopCellEditing(){
                    clicked = false;
                    return super.stopCellEditing();
            }

            protected void fireEditingStopped(){
                    super.fireEditingStopped();
            }
    }


}
```

PendenciaTableModel.java

```
public class PendenciaTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {


    private List<PendenciaModel> dados = new ArrayList<>();
    private String[] colunas = {"Selecionar", "ID", "Pendência", "Data e Hora", "Descrição", "Detalhes"};

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column){
        return colunas[column];
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return colunas.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return dados.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int linha, int coluna) {
        switch(coluna){
            case 0:
                return dados.get(linha).getSelecionado();
            case 1:
                return dados.get(linha).getId();
            case 2:
                return dados.get(linha).getPendencia();
            case 3:
                return dados.get(linha).getDataHora();
            case 4:
                return dados.get(linha).getDescricao();
            case 5:
                return dados.get(linha).getDetalhes();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void addRow(PendenciaModel pm) {
        this.dados.add(pm);
        this.fireTableDataChanged();    
    }

    public void removeRow(int linha){
        this.dados.remove(linha);
        this.fireTableRowsDeleted(linha, linha);
    }



}
```

PendenciaModel.java

```
public class PendenciaModel { 
    private boolean selecionado;
    private int id;
    private String pendencia;
    private Date dataHora;
    private String descricao;
    private String detalhes;

    public boolean getSelecionado() {
        return selecionado;
    }
    public void setSelecionado(boolean selecionado) {
        this.selecionado = selecionado;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getPendencia() {
        return pendencia;
    }
    public void setPendencia(String pendencia) {
        this.pendencia = pendencia;
    }
    public Date getDataHora() {
        return dataHora;
    }
    public void setDataHora(Date dataHora) {
        this.dataHora = dataHora;
    }
    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }
    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }
    public String getDetalhes() {
        return detalhes;
    }
    public void setDetalhes(String detalhes) {
        this.detalhes = detalhes;
    }


}
```

Comment: Tenho um menu (JMenuBar) onde coloquei na ação do clique para adicionar uma instância do PendenciaView na tela. getContentPane().add(new PendenciaView()); (Ele é um JFrame e estou trabalhando com CardLayout)

Comment: Certo, o que o que o codigo precisa fazer q nao faz?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85098/discussion-between-articuno-hexacampao-and-lys).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da forma que está fazendo, além de usar de forma incorreta o `DefaultCellEditor`, que espera um `JTextField` e você está usando um `JButton`, também terá dificuldades depois para recuperar o objeto da linha do botão.

Gostaria de propor uma solução mais robusta, que não precisa utilizar editores e nem renderes,  criada pelo usuário [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1475598/5524514), onde a classe [ButtonColumn](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) adiciona um botão em cada coluna da tabela de forma automática, deixando pra você apenas a parte de definir a ação a ser tomada quando houver o clique.

Para configurar no seu código, basta copiar a classe do link pro seu projeto e instanciar conforme abaixo:

```
ButtonColumn buttonColumn = new ButtonColumn(table, action, columnIndex);
```

onde `table` é a sua tabela, `action` é a ação que o botão terá e `columnIndex` é o índice da coluna onde o botão será exibido.

Para fins demonstrativos, criei a action abaixo que exibe a linha que foi clicada:

```
Action mostrarDetalhes = new AbstractAction() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //recupera a tabela
        JTable table = (JTable)e.getSource();
        //recupera a linha onde houve o clique
        int modelRow = Integer.valueOf(e.getActionCommand());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Linha " + modelRow + " foi clicada");

    }
};

ButtonColumn buttonColumn = new ButtonColumn(table, mostrarDetalhes, 5);
```

O resultado deste exemplo implementado no seu codigo fica:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Apenas salientando o aviso do autor da classe, a coluna precisa ser editável, logo, também é necessário aplicar a dica da resposta do Carlos.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Mais uma vez, obrigado pela disponibilidade e pela paciência.

Answer (score 1):

O seu modelo não permite a edição dos dados - [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#isCellEditable(int,int)) do método `isCellEditable` do `AbstractTableModel`: "Returns false.", ou seja, nenhuma célula vai ser editável, o respectivo `CellEditor` nunca será chamado, portanto o botão não vai ser ativado.

Solução, sobrescrever o método `isCellEditable` para permitir a edição da respectiva coluna:

```
public class PendenciaTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return columnIndex == 5 || super.isCellEditable(rowIndex, columnIndex);
    }
}
```

Obs:

1. em vez de usar diretamente literais (exemplo `5`) para identificar as colunas, é preferível usar constantes `private static final int COL_DETALHE = 5;`
2. (obviamente) a solução acima tambem vale para permitir a edição de outras colunas

Comment: Dessa forma ainda precisa dar 2 cliques(uma para a edição) para funcionar.

Comment: Sua resposta também foi muito útil. Obrigado pela ajuda.